# How to capture 4K screens?

Tags: youtube, video-capture, capturing, 4k

I want to create videos for youtube, but because I am using a 4K screen it is very difficult to find a proper recording solution.
My idea was to buy a card, that I can put into my computer that records my HDMI. (Also the hdmi of my camera)
What are your opinions? Are there better solutions?

Comment: Do you want to capture your screen? Have you tried OBS or ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes I want to make videos... I have never heard of OBS. I tried BB Flashback for example... But it does not work properly in games...

Comment: Try [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)

Comment: It seems that OBS is very cpu intensive?

Comment: Not in my experience. For games, it says, "*GPU-based game capture for high performance game streaming*"

Comment: Oh okay. I have to try it more.. I also have the recording card in my mind...

Comment: It would be cool to see an HDMI solution to this problem, since there are a lot of good reasons not to use screen capture software, including performance and their uncanny knack for messing up your computer.

Answer (score 2):

As you know there are two solutions, one using your **CPU**, the other a dedicated **GPU**.

### CPU Solution

As of today, the CPU solution exit for 4K content, at 60 fps, using x265 or x264 codec. x264 is embededded in OBS in fact, and x264/x265 are known for being the fastest implementation of the standard H264/H265. But, you need a powerful CPU, of course, and then you'll have to make trade off regarding the file size and/or quality. FYI, the x265 has been [demonstrated to be able to live encode H265 stream 4K 60 fps](http://www.multicorewareinc.com/multicoreware-demonstrates-high-quality-4k-10-bit-real-time-hevc-video-encoding-with-x265/), but using a dual socket server (not a standard CPU). It was last year.

### GPU Solution

nVidia released end of year 2015 the fist cards with 2nd generation Maxwell architecture that is the first [allowing H264 4K live encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC).

Since the Ultra High Definition streams needs a lot of resources, you couldn't really find an acceptable solution before new CPU or GPU are released. If I were you I would go with the GPU solution because you could use that card for both display and capture on the fly. If you could afford it of course, such nVidia card are pretty expensive!

Comment: I have an NVIDIA Quadro card and it is *not* fast enough to realtime-encode 4K.

Comment: Quadro are not Maxwell 2nd gen. You need GeForce 9XX if I remember well